# How to redirect a user to chrome extension tabs page from NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, express, google-chrome-extension, jwt, passport.js

I'm working on an extension (MV3) and I'm using Passport.JS to authenticate users with Google. I'm using JWT which I need to send to the frontend. When I try to use the following code to redirect the user to the tabs page of my extension. I get an error.

```
app.get(
    ROUTES.AUTH_GOOGLE_CALLBACK,
    passport.authenticate("google", {
        failureRedirect: `${process.env.CLIENT_URI}/auth/sign-in?errorCode=500`,
    }),
    async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
        try {
            const user = req.user;
            const token = await signAccessToken(user);
            res.status(200).redirect(`chrome-extension://${EXTENSION_KEY}/tabs/auth.html?token=${token}`);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("ERROR IN GOOGLE OAUTH HANDLER::", error);
            res.status(500).json({ error });
        }
    },
);
```

[image]

Expected results -> It should show the tabs page.

I tried adding this in the manifest file but it didnt worked. I just want to send back an access code from the backend, to the extension using Passport JS.

```
   "web_accessible_resources": [
            {
                "resources": [
                    "tabs/auth.html"
                ],
                "matches": [
                    "chrome-extension://<extension key>/*"
                ]
            }
        ],
```

Comment: Replace chrome-extension URL in `matches` with the pattern for the site which performs the redirect e.g. `*://*.example.com/*`

Comment: @wOxxOm I'm working locally so I added local host http://localhost:8080/*

 it didn't worked.

Comment: It may be a bug in Chrome when a port is specified, so try removing it. Don't forget to reload your extension.

Comment: @wOxxOm Does not work,  "matches": ["http://localhost:*/*"] and I've tried using other combinations as well. Neither of them works

Comment: You're still specifying a port. Try removing `:*`.